# Relationship between Pigeonhole Principle and Hall's Theorem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle, matching-theory

I am wondering if there is any sort of relationship between the Generalized Pigeon Hole Principle and Hall's Theorem. For example, is possible to use the Pigeonhole Principle in order to prove that there does not exist a perfect matching between two sets?